# SubQuery for getting open and close projects

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I am looking for a subquery to get the **data from sales and the count on status of the project Status as a separate column open and close where the total count of the open project will come under dummy column "open" and the Total count of the closed project will come under"Close" Dummy column  based on the corresponding status id where 4 is for close and (1,2,3,5) are for open for the provided EmpId and display them in separate dummy column "open" and "Close"**
where the status will display as either open and close. And also if the user id is manager then it will show the data up to level 1 else it will display the data of that user Id i.e root.

Here is the table description:

- Sales: column [EmpId,Status,status description,EmpId]
  **status id where 4 is for close and (1,2,3,5) are for open
  The status will have status the project i.e open, close for that emp Under sales**
- Emp:column[EmpId,Ename..EmpEducation..]
- EmpManager: Column[EmpId,EmpManagerId(both are Fk to table Emp)

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: *Here is the table description:* Non-useful. Show CREATE TABLE scripts. Also add INSERT INTO with sample data and table-formatted desired output. Additionally select **one** DBMS (remove wrong tag), providing its version.

Comment: @ishabhardwaj . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.